# Delphi IBDatabase what to do in case of a disconnect?

Tags: database, delphi, delphi-xe2, firebird2.5

I am trying to solve a big problem (For me at the moment) and hope you can help me.

My application connects to a database at the start and stays connected while the application is running. The problem occurs when the connection is lost. It just stays disconnected until I restart my application.

The error message is :

> Unable to complete network request to host "USER-PC".
>   Error writing data to the connection.
>   An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

If I disconnect and connect that solves the problem as well, but how can I do that automatically? How can I detect that the connection has been lost?

The connection to DB:

```
 IBDataBase1.DatabaseName := ServerName + '/' + ServerPort + ':' +
 'LOCAL';
     try
       IBDataBase1.Connected := True;
       Result := True;
     except on E:Exception do begin
       MessageDlg(Message_2 + #13#10 + e.Message, mtError, [mbOk],0);
     end;
```

The database I use is Firebird 2.5, and the component is IBDatabase, and for connection I use an alias. The question is how do I catch that exception and when? I have a large number of different forms.

Comment: Post some code. In general you should catch an exception and try to reconnect when needed.

Comment: which db access library do you use ? also please edit tags below questions and specify delphi version

Comment: If general network status is ok, then - in Firebird 3.0 -  there would be OnDisconnect trigger, that potentially can be used to send message via other network services. However when FB 3 would be released and ready for production no one knows

Comment: @Arioch'The Disconnect triggers are database side, so won't help with this issue. Also they have existed since Firebird 2.1: http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-ddl-trigger.html (under _Database triggers_)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel that's why i said about sending signals by other means, than FB itself. Make UDD and send XMPP message or call XML-RPC or whatever. As long as - i repeat it - the network works in general. Thanks for noting about 2.1

Comment: im  confused... dont know what to do :/

Comment: So how could i make something to know if i have been disconnected from the server?